# Access the 2nd column foreign key value linked to primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a table `Batches` where `DispatchBy` and `DispatchTo` is linked to a primary key table: `Users`.

In the view I'm using the following code to get the `DispatchBy` `UserName` from Users table. How do I get the `DispatchTo`  `UserName`?

```
 @foreach ( var item in Model.Batches)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th>@item.User.UserName</th>
                        <th>@item.DispatchByStatus</th>
                        <th>@item.DispatchByTimestamp</th>
                        <th>@item.User1.UserName</th>
                        <th>@item.DispatchToStatus</th>
                        <th>@item.DispatchToTimestamp</th>
                    </tr>
                }
```

**Table**: Batches

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Batches] (
    [BTransactionID]      INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BatchID]             INT          NULL,
    [TaxPayerTIN]         VARCHAR (9)  NOT NULL,
    [Qty]                 INT          NOT NULL,
    [DispatchBy]          INT          NOT NULL,
    [DispatchByStatus]    VARCHAR (11) NOT NULL,
    [DispatchByTimestamp] DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [DispatchTo]          INT          NULL,
    [DispatchToStatus]    VARCHAR (11) NULL,
    [DispatchToTimestamp] DATETIME     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Batch] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BTransactionID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Batches_Users1] FOREIGN KEY ([DispatchTo]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Batches_Users] FOREIGN KEY ([DispatchBy]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID])
);
```

**Table**: Users

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [UserID]           INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName]         VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [UserEmail]        VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [UserPassword]     VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [UserPasswordSalt] VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [UserRoleID]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentID]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [UserCreated]      DATETIME      NOT NULL,
    [UserStatus]       VARCHAR (11)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Users_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_Departments] FOREIGN KEY ([DepartmentID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Departments] ([DepartmentID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_Roles] FOREIGN KEY ([UserRoleID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Roles] ([RoleID])
);
```

**Model**: Batch.cs

```
public partial class Batch
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Batch()
    {
        this.Collections = new HashSet<Collection>();
    }

    public int BTransactionID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BatchID { get; set; }
    public string TaxPayerTIN { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public int DispatchBy { get; set; }
    public string DispatchByStatus { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DispatchByTimestamp { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DispatchTo { get; set; }
    public string DispatchToStatus { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DispatchToTimestamp { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `<th>@item.User.UserName</th>` ? I suggest renaming the `User` and `User1` properties in the `Batch` class to meaningful names (Ex : `DispatchToUser` , `DispatchByUser`) to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I don't know what I did and what so ever but it's working now.